# Order by one of the keys of composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.0, sql-order-by

I have a table with columns named like,

```
    month    year    id    updated_by
-------------------------------------------
    02     2012     1       'entity1'
    03     2012     2        'e2'
```

where composite keys are `month`, `year` and `id`. Now I would like to sort by `id` in the ascending order.

But using `order by id` does not yield a sorted resultset by `id`.

What am I missing here? Would be glad for any help directing me towards the answer.

Edit: I am using MySQL 5.0

Comment: Sort where, dierctly in the table or as the result set of a query? And what is the database backend, it could make a difference in the correct answer.

Comment: @HLGEM In the table. I forgot to mention I am using MySQL 5.0

Comment: Is `id` an integer column or a `VARCHAR`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

You are saying that the query:

```
select *
from t
order by id
```

is *not* ordering the table by `id`.  If so, this would indicate a bug in MySQL, which is unlikely.

Some thoughts:

(1) Perhaps you are doing this in a subquery.  The ordering is not guaranteed when done in a subquery.

(2) Perhaps you are expecting an ordering on `id` to order by the elements of the composite index.  That would be an incorrect expectation.  Order by the things you want to order on.

(3) Perhaps id is being stored as a character string, but contains only digits.  If so, then `'10'` will come before `'9'`.

Can you show what query you are using and the results that you are getting?

Comment: I made a mistake of using varchar in id column. Nevertheless your answer is helpful and covers it. Thanks!